# Design involving conversions between data formats in .NET

Tags: .net, entity-framework, type-conversion

We are building a new web service, which will return data in a specific, public metadata format.

We currently have a database system, which was designed around the same format, but not conforming to it exactly, because of pre-existing data that needed to be migrated across and maintained without any loss of data.

For building applications that use the database, I have created a single assembly, with an Entity Framework project inside.  This assembly can then be used by any solution which wishes to interact with the database.

For the web service project, the public metadata format has an xml schema which I've turned into C# classes using .NET's xsd.exe tool (very convenient).  Essentially, the web service will return objects from the database, but in the format defined by the aforementioned metadata format.  This means that some form of translation/conversion will need to take place to get the Entity Framework objects into the public metadata format objects, which will then be returned by the web service.

Assuming I have DBEntities.dll, and PublicMetadataFormat.dll, what would be the best way to go about "translating" these formats, in terms of design?

Here are the possibilities I've thought of:

- Creating some static extension classes that convert between the two formats.  Eg, EFEntity.ToMetadataFormat(), or MetadataFormat.ToEFEntity().
- In the respective projects, implement explicit or implicit operators that will permit casting between the two formats.
- Implementing IConvertible on each, to allow conversion between the two formats.
- Creating two TypeConverter classes, and applying them to each format.

The only option I really like from the above is the static extension class idea, because it allows both assemblies to remain unmodified, and leaves them uncoupled.  It also allows different implementations of the conversion across solutions.

Eventually what I'd like to do is create a LINQ provider for the public metadata format too, like there is already for the Entity Framework objects, into which I could inject a "converter" object that controls how the database objects are translated into the metadata objects.

Does anyone have any experience in translating or converting between two loosely related formats, like this?  How best to approach it?

Regards,
Nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used it myself but this sounds like a job for [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/)